# How to add multiple string values to a cell in a excel sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

My code below check if column S and T cells are empty or not. If the cells are empty a text goes into column U saying it cannot be blank.
My Problem is the cell can take one string at a time, i am looking for a way to concatenate the string in a single cell. Please help. Thanks.

My Code:

```
        For pos2 = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 Step 1

            If (IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "S").Value) = True) Then
                .Cells(pos2, "U").Value = "Description can't be blank"
            End If

            If (IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "T").Value) = True) Then
                .Cells(pos2, "U").Value = "Criteria can't be blank"
            End If
       Next pos2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `String` to store the type of errors you want to write in Column "U":

```
Dim ErrStr      As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    For pos2 = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 Step 1
        ErrStr = "" ' reset the error string for each row

        If IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "S").Value) Then
           ErrStr = "Description can't be blank"
        End If

        If IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "T").Value) Then
            ' just to make it clearer
            If ErrStr <> "" Then
                ErrStr = ErrStr & " ; "
            End If

            ErrStr = ErrStr & "Criteria can't be blank"
        End If

        .Cells(pos2, "U").Value = ErrStr
    Next pos2

End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Store the string in a string variable, rather than writing it directly into the cell. Something like:

```
Dim strErrors as string

    For pos2 = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 Step 1

        If (IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "S").Value) = True) Then
            strErrors = "Description can't be blank.  "
        End If

        If (IsEmpty(.Cells(pos2, "T").Value) = True) Then
            strErrors = strErrors & "Criteria can't be blank"
        End If 
        .cells(pos2, "U").value = strErrors
   Next pos2
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `&` like

```
.Cells(pos2, "U").Value = .Cells(pos2, "U").Value & "Criteria can't be blank"
```